# How to remove cell space in UICollectionView Flow layout size?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am customizing collection view layout into 3 columns [left side 2 cell & right side 1 portrait cell]. I am unable to remove top space of let side 2 cells.

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

extension UICollectionView{

    func getSize(noOfCellsInRow: Int, isPotrait: Bool = true)->CGSize{


        let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

        let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
                 + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
                 + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow - 1))

        let size = Int((self.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow))

        return CGSize(width: size, height: isPotrait ? size+size : size)
    }
}

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
    return cell
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

      if indexPath.row == 1{
         return collectionView.getSize(noOfCellsInRow: 2,isPotrait: true)
      }else{
        return collectionView.getSize(noOfCellsInRow: 2,isPotrait: false)
     }

    }
}
```

**Output of the corresponding code**:

[image]

**Expected output**:

[image]

How can I make it work? Any idea will help me lot. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've customized Apple's MosaicLayout example to fit your expected output.

[image]

Here is the custom UICollectionViewLayout, with `twoFiftyFifty` added as this segment style.

```
enum MosaicSegmentStyle {
    case twoFiftyFifty
    case fullWidth
    case fiftyFifty
    case twoThirdsOneThird
    case oneThirdTwoThirds
}

class MosaicLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    var contentBounds = CGRect.zero
    var cachedAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    /// - Tag: PrepareMosaicLayout
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }

        // Reset cached information.
        cachedAttributes.removeAll()
        contentBounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: collectionView.bounds.size)

        // For every item in the collection view:
        //  - Prepare the attributes.
        //  - Store attributes in the cachedAttributes array.
        //  - Combine contentBounds with attributes.frame.
        let count = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)

        var currentIndex = 0
        var segment: MosaicSegmentStyle = .fiftyFifty
        var lastFrame: CGRect = .zero

        let cvWidth = collectionView.bounds.size.width

        while currentIndex < count {
            let segmentFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: lastFrame.maxY + 1.0, width: cvWidth, height: (self.collectionView?.frame.width)!)

            var segmentRects = [CGRect]()
            switch segment {
            case .twoFiftyFifty:
                let horizontalSlices = segmentFrame.dividedIntegral(fraction:0.5, from: .minXEdge)
                let verticalSlices = horizontalSlices.first.dividedIntegral(fraction: 0.5, from: .minYEdge)
                segmentRects = [verticalSlices.first, verticalSlices.second, horizontalSlices.second]

            case .fullWidth:
                segmentRects = [segmentFrame]

            case .fiftyFifty:
                let horizontalSlices = segmentFrame.dividedIntegral(fraction: 0.5, from: .minXEdge)
                segmentRects = [horizontalSlices.first, horizontalSlices.second]

            case .twoThirdsOneThird:
                let horizontalSlices = segmentFrame.dividedIntegral(fraction: (2.0 / 3.0), from: .minXEdge)
                let verticalSlices = horizontalSlices.second.dividedIntegral(fraction: 0.5, from: .minYEdge)
                segmentRects = [horizontalSlices.first, verticalSlices.first, verticalSlices.second]

            case .oneThirdTwoThirds:
                let horizontalSlices = segmentFrame.dividedIntegral(fraction: (1.0 / 3.0), from: .minXEdge)
                let verticalSlices = horizontalSlices.first.dividedIntegral(fraction: 0.5, from: .minYEdge)
                segmentRects = [verticalSlices.first, verticalSlices.second, horizontalSlices.second]
            }

            // Create and cache layout attributes for calculated frames.
            for rect in segmentRects {
                let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: IndexPath(item: currentIndex, section: 0))
                attributes.frame = rect

                cachedAttributes.append(attributes)
```

//                    contentBounds = contentBounds.union(lastFrame)
                    contentBounds = contentBounds.union(rect)

```
                currentIndex += 1
                lastFrame = rect
            }

//            // Determine the next segment style.
//            switch count - currentIndex {
//            case 1:
//                segment = .fullWidth
//            case 2:
//                segment = .fiftyFifty
//            default:
//                switch segment {
//                case .fullWidth:
//                    segment = .fiftyFifty
//                case .fiftyFifty:
//                    segment = .twoThirdsOneThird
//                case .twoThirdsOneThird:
//                    segment = .oneThirdTwoThirds
//                case .oneThirdTwoThirds:
//                    segment = .fiftyFifty
//                }
//            }
        }
    }

    /// - Tag: CollectionViewContentSize
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return contentBounds.size
    }

    /// - Tag: ShouldInvalidateLayout
    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return false }
        return !newBounds.size.equalTo(collectionView.bounds.size)
    }

    /// - Tag: LayoutAttributesForItem
    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cachedAttributes[indexPath.item]
    }

    /// - Tag: LayoutAttributesForElements
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var attributesArray = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Find any cell that sits within the query rect.
        guard let lastIndex = cachedAttributes.indices.last,
              let firstMatchIndex = binSearch(rect, start: 0, end: lastIndex) else { return attributesArray }

        // Starting from the match, loop up and down through the array until all the attributes
        // have been added within the query rect.
        for attributes in cachedAttributes[..<firstMatchIndex].reversed() {
            guard attributes.frame.maxY >= rect.minY else { break }
            attributesArray.append(attributes)
        }

        for attributes in cachedAttributes[firstMatchIndex...] {
            guard attributes.frame.minY <= rect.maxY else { break }
            attributesArray.append(attributes)
        }

        return attributesArray
    }

    // Perform a binary search on the cached attributes array.
    func binSearch(_ rect: CGRect, start: Int, end: Int) -> Int? {
        if end < start { return nil }

        let mid = (start + end) / 2
        let attr = cachedAttributes[mid]

        if attr.frame.intersects(rect) {
            return mid
        } else {
            if attr.frame.maxY < rect.minY {
                return binSearch(rect, start: (mid + 1), end: end)
            } else {
                return binSearch(rect, start: start, end: (mid - 1))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The divideIntegral extension:

```
extension CGRect {
    func dividedIntegral(fraction: CGFloat, from fromEdge: CGRectEdge) -> (first: CGRect, second: CGRect) {
        let dimension: CGFloat

        switch fromEdge {
        case .minXEdge, .maxXEdge:
            dimension = self.size.width
        case .minYEdge, .maxYEdge:
            dimension = self.size.height
        }

        let distance = (dimension * fraction).rounded(.up)
        var slices = self.divided(atDistance: distance, from: fromEdge)

        switch fromEdge {
        case .minXEdge, .maxXEdge:
            slices.remainder.origin.x += 1
            slices.remainder.size.width -= 1
        case .minYEdge, .maxYEdge:
            slices.remainder.origin.y += 1
            slices.remainder.size.height -= 1
        }

        return (first: slices.slice, second: slices.remainder)
    }
}
```

The MosaicCell class:

```
class MosaicCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifer = "kMosaicCollectionViewCell"

    var imageView = UIImageView()
    var assetIdentifier: String?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.autoresizesSubviews = true

        imageView.frame = self.bounds
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(imageView)

        // Use a random background color.
        let redColor = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
        let greenColor = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
        let blueColor = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redColor, green: greenColor, blue: blueColor, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        imageView.image = nil
        assetIdentifier = nil
    }
}
```

Your ViewController class:

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let mosaicLayout = MosaicLayout()
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: mosaicLayout)
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        collectionView.indicatorStyle = .white
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(MosaicCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MosaicCell.identifer)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MosaicCell.identifer, for: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }
}
```

> Here is the link to the Apple example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/customizing_collection_view_layouts
>
> You will need to configure later segments as desired.

Comment: Happy to help, @MountAin!

Comment: One help, I can't make 3 rows. I am able to make upto 2 rows only. I tried with sections but not works. Can you help me to make 3 rows fullWidth. Here is video https://streamable.com/b2yac5

Comment: Here is what I modified in code `segmentRects = [ CGRect(x: 0, y: lastFrame.maxY + 1.0, width: cvWidth, height: cvWidth/1.5)]`

Comment: The third row is not in bounds

Comment: @MountAin, you found a bug in the Apple example code. Good job! I have updated my answer to fix this. `contentBounds = contentBounds.union(lastFrame)` was not picking up the last cell so I've changed it to `contentBounds = contentBounds.union(rect)`. I've confirmed it as working for me. Please lemme know if it fixes it for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need custom your own custom [UICollectionViewLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout) like [PinterestLayout](https://github.com/MagicLab-team/PinterestLayout), the system builtin `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` only works for grid layout.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I will try